How to get correct rotation matrix from two vectors?
Problem:
According to a 3D coordinate axes, there exists a vector, v1. Now, this 3D coordinate axes rotates by a certain yaw, then pitch, then roll. Now, the vector existing in the space appears different due to the rotation. Let's call this vector, v2.
How can I get the rotation matrix of this rotation solely based on v1 and v2?
This has been asked many times but I can never simulate the correct results. For example, according to a working simulation, v1 and v2 are:
v1 = [0.577; 0.577; 0.577];

v2 = [0.804; 0.142; 0.577];
Here, v1 is the original vector and v2 is it after yawing the coordinate axes by 35 degrees.
I have tried to solve this in MATLAB with the following code. Although the rotation matrix correctly rotates v1 to v2, the Euler angles are wrong. I expect to see 35, 0, 0 for yaw, pitch and roll since I only yawed the coordinate axes. I also calculated the correct matrix to be:
[[ 0.81965227 -0.57286137  0.        ]
 [ 0.57286137  0.81965227  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          1.        ]]

Code:
v1 = [0.5773502691896257; 0.5773502691896257; 0.5773502691896257];
v2 = [0.8039691860428207; 0.14247882144484117; 0.5773502691896257];
c = cross(v1, v2);
a = c / norm(c);

angle = acos(dot(v1, v2));

axang = [a(1) a(2) a(3) angle];
rotm = axang2rotm(axang);

disp("v1:");
disp(v1);
disp("v2:");
disp(v2);

disp("Rotation matrix:");
disp(rotm);

disp("Apply rotation matrix to v1 to get v2:");
disp(rotm * v1);

eul = rotm2eul(rotm, "ZYX") * 180 / pi

Output:
v1:
    0.5774
    0.5774
    0.5774

v2:
    0.8040
    0.1425
    0.5774

Rotation matrix:
    0.9133    0.3994    0.0798
   -0.3644    0.8889   -0.2777
   -0.1818    0.2245    0.9574

Apply rotation matrix to v1 to get v2:
    0.8040
    0.1425
    0.5774


eul =

  -21.7536   10.4775   13.1968


There are multiple rotation matrices that transform one vector to another. To see why, suppose you have a rotation matrix M that transforms v1 to v2, so R.v1 = v2. Suppose another rotation matrix P has v2 as its axis of rotation, then P.v2=v2. Then P.(R.v1) = P.v2 = v2, so R and P.R are rotation matrices that transform v1 into v2. Therefore, you shouldn't expect to get back a particular set of euler angles, you would need additional constraints. For example, if you knew how two linearly independent vectors were transformed by a rotation matrix then you could recover that matrix.

@jodag, thanks. I understand that. However, when I physically rotate the coordinate axes by the euler angles from the MATLAB script (the "incorrect ones"), it doesn't actually rotate the vector v1 to v2.

That sounds like a different problem than the one discussed here. If i remember correctly, matlab functions interpret rotation matrices as premultiply operators. I.e. they assume that a rotation matrix is applied to a vector using v1R rather than Rv1. Try transposing your rotation matrix when you pass it to rotm2eul and see if that resolves your issue, otherwise please update your question with the additional information needed to reproduce your issue.

Hey @jodag. Thank you. It seemed that my previous comment was based on an incorrect observation. I can conclude that there are multiple rotation matrices for a rotation from one vector to another as you mentioned. And, each of these obviously have their own Euler angles.
It could be possible to find what I called the "real" Euler angles by finding solution which also have the smallest absolute sum of the 3 angles. For instance, if I yaw 30 degrees. The rotation matrix which is the most accurate representation of this rotation is the one where the |yaw| + |pitch| + |roll| is smallest.
